# What's the difference between Pick's formula and the Shoelace formula(Gausse's formula)?

Tags: geometry, area

So I was thinking of making a GUI in Python that calculates the area of a shape that the user draws. Therefore, I would need some sort of equation to find the area. I googled it and I found the Shoelace formula(made by Gauss himself); right here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

I read it and all of their examples are for polygons. But the user can draw circular shapes, so I did more research and found Pick's formula; right here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYmemgPa87I

And I think that Pick's formula is a lot easier to use. But what's the difference? Is there one better than the other or do they have their pros and cons? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> But what's the difference?

[Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) works only if the polygon vertices have integer coordinates.

[Shoelace formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) works with any real coordinates.

---

If you have a sequence of tuples corresponding to the consecutive points along the path the user drew, then the Shoelace formula is trivial to implement.

Let's say `path` is that sequence, with `path[0]` being the starting point, and `path[len(path)-1]` the final point.  Then, we can use the fact that in Python, `path[len(path)-1] == path[-1]`:

```
def pathArea(path):
    # Less than three points, and the area is zero.
    if len(path) < 3:
        return 0

    A = 0.0
    for i in range(0, len(path)):
        A += path[i-1][0] * path[i][1] - path[i][0] * path[i-1][1]

    return 0.5 * abs(A)
```

Mathematically, the above uses
$$A = \frac{1}{2}\left\lvert \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_{i-1} y_{i} - x_{i} y_{i-1} \right\rvert$$
where $n$ is `len(path)`, and $x_{-1} = x_{n-1}$ and $y_{-1} = y_{n-1}$ matching the final point in `path`.

---

When drawing, you can use line segments between the points, but note that you'll only want to add a new vertex if it differs from the previous one.  So, if `self.currentPath` is the path being drawn, and `newX` and `newY` are the current coordinates being drawn, use

```
    if (self.currentPath is None) or (len(self.currentPath) < 1):
        self.currentPath = [ (newX, newY) ]
    elif (self.currentPath[-1][0] != newX) or (self.currentPath[-1][1] != newY):
        self.currentPath.append( (newX, newY) ]
```

so that the vertex list will not contain consecutive duplicate points.

Note that the above `pathArea()` function does not need the path to be closed, to start and end with the same point; there is an implicit line segment (polygon side) between the starting and the ending point.

If the user draws a closed figure with line segments poking out, drawing α instead of a nice circle, you will need to trim off the extra vertices.  Otherwise the actual area calculated is that of a fish shape, as an extra line segment is added between the starting and ending points.

To do that, you need to find vertex $S$ near the beginning of the path, and vertex $E$ near the end of the path, such that the line segment from the vertex $S$ to the next vertex (from $(x_S , y_S)$ to $(x_{S+1}, y_{S+1})$), intersects the line segment from the vertex preceding $E$ to vertex $E$ (from $(x_{E-1}, y_{E-1})$ to $(x_E , y_E)$); with $S < E$.  If you find the intersection, remove all initial vertices on the path up to $S$, and all vertices from $E$ to end, including both vertices $S$ and $E$, and prepend or append the intersection point to the path.